# Python findall in a string

Tags: python, string, find

There must be an easier way or function to do this code here:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python

    string = "test [*string*] test [*st[ *ring*] test"

    points = []

    result = string.find("[*")
    new_string = string[result+1:]

    while result != -1:
      points.append(result)
      new_string = new_string[result+1:]
      result = new_string.find("[*")

    print points
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  import re
  string = "test [*string*] test [*st[ *ring*] test"

  points = [m.start() for m in re.finditer('\[', string)]
```

Comment: I thought there was probably a way to do this with `re`.  Thanks for posting.

Comment: running your code gives me `sre_constants.error: unexpected end of regular expression.
`

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary -- You're right.  it should be `re.finditer(r'\[',string)`

Comment: oops..forgot a backslash..added!

Comment: Oh character classes ... who needs em? ;)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to get the indices in the string that match `'[*'`...

```
indices=[i for i in range(len(string)-1) if string[i:i+2] == '[*']
```

But this output is different than what your code will produce.  Can you verify that your code does what you want?

Also note that `string` is the name of a python module in the standard library -- while it isn't used very often, it's probably a good idea to avoid using it as a variable name.  (don't use `str` either)

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> indexes = lambda str_, pattern: reduce(
...    lambda acc, x: acc + [acc[-1] + len(x) + len(pattern)],
...    str_.split(pattern), [-len(pattern)])[1:-1]
>>> indexes('123(456(', '(')
[3, 7]
>>> indexes('', 'x')
[]
>>> indexes("test [*string*] test [*st[ *ring*] test", '[*')
[5, 21]
>>> indexes('1231231','1')
[0, 3, 6]
```